# Abelian/Non-Abelian Groups and Inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have a group $\left(G,*\right)$ without knowing whether it is abelian or not, then:

If $\left(a*b\right)' \neq a'*b'$ (where a' is the inverse of a) can we conclude that commutativity does not hold over * and G is non-Abelian?

My reasoning is that for any group we can prove using associativity that $\left(a*b\right)' = b'*a'$, but we can only prove that $\left(a*b\right)' = a'*b'$ if the group is Abelian (by swapping the elements on the RHS).

An example of when this works/doesn't work would be super-helpful.

I'm fairly new to abstract algebra and college-level maths in general so it's quite possible I missed something along the line definition-wise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you denote $a', b'$, &c.?

Comment: Assuming $a'$ means $a^{-1}$, then commutativity tells us that $(a*b)^{-1}=a^{-1}*b^{-1}$ so if you have $a,b$ for which this does not hold then your group is not commutative.  If $a'$ means something else, you should provide more information.

Comment: I highly recommend you not use prime notation for inverses. This is going to lead to issues down the road and is very nonstandard notation. Use -1 notation instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because you know (a.b)'=b'.a', if its different than a'.b' then it's because the group isn't commutative. The group of invertible 2x2 matrices is an example of such a group